# envoy proxy not logging requests

Tags: envoyproxy

I am trying to access a gRPC endpoint with envoy. I trying to call the envoy container via localhost:8081 and it should reroute the traffic to localhost:8080. However I see no logs even though that appear to be enabled.

envoy.yaml

```
admin:
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 127.0.0.1, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 127.0.0.1, port_value: 8081 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                codec_type: AUTO
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route: { cluster: some_service }
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
    - name: some_service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: STATIC
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: some_service
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 127.0.0.1
                      port_value: 8080
```

logs:

```
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.502][9][info][admin] [source/server/admin/admin.cc:67] admin address: 127.0.0.1:9901
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.502][9][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:131] loading tracing configuration
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.502][9][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:91] loading 0 static secret(s)
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.502][9][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:97] loading 1 cluster(s)
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.511][9][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:101] loading 1 listener(s)
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.514][9][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:113] loading stats configuration
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.514][9][info][runtime] [source/common/runtime/runtime_impl.cc:463] RTDS has finished initialization
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.514][9][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:226] cm init: all clusters initialized
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.514][9][warning][main] [source/server/server.cc:794] there is no configured limit to the number of allowed active connections. Set a limit via the runtime key overload.global_downstream_max_connections
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.517][9][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:896] all clusters initialized. initializing init manager
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.517][9][info][config] [source/extensions/listener_managers/listener_manager/listener_manager_impl.cc:852] all dependencies initialized. starting workers
[2023-01-17 13:21:20.520][9][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:915] starting main dispatch loop
[2023-01-17 13:36:19.810][9][info][main] [source/server/drain_manager_impl.cc:171] shutting down parent after drain
```

docker

```
af885ab28109   poc_gateway            "/docker-entrypoint.…"   33 minutes ago   Up 33 minutes   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp, 10000/tcp   gateway
```

advice? Am I configuring the logs correctly?

Comment: Do you wish to enable HTTP access logs to stdout?

Comment: @ns15 I just want logs...

Comment: Envoy server logs are already getting logged. You have shared the snippet of logs above. This server log is enabled by default. Additionally if you want the finer details, you can change the log level. Apart from server logs, there is access logs which will log HTTP path, duration, client details, request headers etc.. This access log will have to be enabled separately.